# Htaccess to Nginx with pre-configured options

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I have a website that run under nginx, with directives applied by Cloudpanel and i want to add my crm on it, the crm have 2 .htaccess file, one in the root folder and one in the /public folder.

I'm trying by 2 days to convert the htaccess into nginx directives and add them to the vhosts file that cloudpanel let me edit.

This is the .htaccess of the root folder (very easy):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js|custom)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

And this is the .htaccess of the /public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And i have to add their directives into my Cloudpanel vhost file i guess, i come from Apache so maybe i'm wrong with this, anyway this is the file i currently have:

```
server {
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;
server_name crm.deppastudios.it;
{{root}}

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
index index.php index.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
}

if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
{{ssl_certificate_key}}
{{ssl_certificate}}
server_name crm.deppastudios.it;
{{root}}

{{nginx_access_log}}
{{nginx_error_log}}

if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
}

location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
}

{{settings}}

location / {
    {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    

}

location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
}




if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
}
}
```

Please help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: `.htaccess` is Apache HTTPD feature (where it was *never recommended* to use anyway), and Nginx doesn't support it and has nothing to replace its functional. Look for ways to translate the Apache directives from .htaccess into appropriate Nginx configuration options and put them into its configuration file. ServerFault has plenty of answered (resolved) questions about how to do that.